# Compositing images with fresh context?

Tags: cocoa, layer, composite

I am trying to draw one image onto another and then output that composite image as an image file. The method works fine the first time I call it but any subsequent calls layer another image upon the last composite. I.e. it keeps layering instead of getting a new background image.

I hope I have made myself clear (its a little hard to explain) any help would be much appreciated.

```
-(NSImage *)compositeImage:(NSImage *)overlay Onto:(NSImage *)background AtPoint:(NSPoint)location{
NSImage *returnImage;

[background lockFocus];

[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[overlay drawInRect:NSMakeRect(location.x, location.y, [overlay size].width, [overlay size].width) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

[background unlockFocus];

returnImage = background;

return returnImage;
```

}

Comment: How you are passing background image to this function?

Comment: @ParagBafna I am creating an NSImage, giving it an image from the app recourses and then giving it the result of the above method with itself as the background variable. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should copy the image before drawing it, so you don't change the original.

```
-(NSImage *)compositeImage:(NSImage *)overlay Onto:(NSImage *)background AtPoint:(NSPoint)location{
NSImage * backgroundCopy = [background copy]; 
[backgroundCopy lockFocus];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[overlay drawInRect:NSMakeRect(location.x, location.y, [overlay size].width, [overlay size].width) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
[backgroundCopy unlockFocus];
return backgroundCopy; //release this object in calling function.
}
```

Comment: I don't own one to test on... can anyone verify how well this works on a retina screen? Is simply using @2x images enough, or do some parameters of the draw in rect command need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Parag Bafna 's answer, in Swift 3

```
func draw(image: NSImage, onto backgroundImage: NSImage) -> NSImage? {
  guard let canvas = backgroundImage.copy() as? NSImage else {
    return nil
  }

  canvas.lockFocus()
  NSGraphicsContext.current()?.imageInterpolation = NSImageInterpolation.high
  image.draw(at: .zero,
             from: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: backgroundImage.size),
             operation: .sourceOver,
             fraction: 1.0)

  canvas.unlockFocus()

  return canvas
}
```